# Error installing VS2010 - 'Cannot install; setup files are not available."

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm currently installing VS2010 and getting an error stating:
"Cannot install; setup files are not available."

I had VS2012 on the machine previously and I installed the components through 'Add/Remove Programs'.

Anyone any ideas of what the problem might be ??

I'll post the error log as well:

[08/26/14,11:29:34] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Premium - ENU: [2] CRootComponent::Install(): Cannot install; setup files are not available.
[08/26/14,11:29:34] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023284.
[08/26/14,11:29:34] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Premium - ENU is not installed.

Comment: Sorry - big error log . . .

Comment: You've included dozens of log entries that are all repetitions of the same information, and all related to the initial line (all of the dependent files can't be installed if the installation files can't be found, clearly). Please learn to actually **read the words** in error messages, as they usually have meaning. In this case, the only relevant content is in the very first line, which you included in your subject line.